# how to join single array and multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I'm trying to combine one array with a multidimensional array, I've tried to use array combine but on keys that exist in multidimensional arrays replaced with with data from single array
please help me and sry bad language cause i using google translate
my example array

```
  Array
    (
        [A] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => biologi
                [ruangan] => ruangan1
                [guru] => Bapak Ringgo
            )
    
        [B] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => fisika
                [ruangan] => ruangan2
                [guru] => Bapak Gugun
            )
    
        [C] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => matematika
                [ruangan] => ruangan3
                [guru] => Bapak Maman
            )
    
        [D] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => bahasa
                [ruangan] => ruangan4
                [guru] => Ibu Anik
            )
    
        [E] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => olahraga
                [ruangan] => ruangan5
                [guru] => Ibu Lia
            )
    
        [F] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => sejarah
                [ruangan] => ruangan6
                [guru] => Ibu ucik
            )
    
    )
```

single array

```
Array
(
    [0] => senin
    [1] => selasa
    [2] => rabu
    [3] => kamis
    [4] => jumat
    [5] => sabtu
)
```

result i want

```
senin=>array(
     [A] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => biologi
                [ruangan] => ruangan1
                [guru] => Bapak Ringgo
            )
    
        [B] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => fisika
                [ruangan] => ruangan2
                [guru] => Bapak Gugun
            )
    
        [C] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => matematika
                [ruangan] => ruangan3
                [guru] => Bapak Maman
            )
    
        [D] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => bahasa
                [ruangan] => ruangan4
                [guru] => Bapak Gugun
            )
    
        [E] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => olahraga
                [ruangan] => ruangan5
                [guru] => Bapak Ringgo
            )
    
        [F] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => sejarah
                [ruangan] => ruangan6
                [guru] => Bapak Maman
            )
)

selasa=>array(
     [A] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => Matematika
                [ruangan] => ruangan1
                [guru] => Bapak Ringgo
            )
    
        [B] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => bahasa indonesia
                [ruangan] => ruangan2
                [guru] => Bapak Gugun
            )
    
        [C] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => fisika
                [ruangan] => ruangan3
                [guru] => Bapak Maman
            )
    
        [D] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => bahasa
                [ruangan] => ruangan4
                [guru] => Bapak Ringgo
            )
    
        [E] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => olahraga
                [ruangan] => ruangan5
                [guru] => Bapak Maman
            )
    
        [F] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => sejarah
                [ruangan] => ruangan6
                [guru] => Bapak Gugun
            )
    
)

rabu=>array(
     [A] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => biologi
                [ruangan] => ruangan1
                [guru] => Bapak Ringgo
            )
    
        [B] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => fisika
                [ruangan] => ruangan2
                [guru] => Bapak Gugun
            )
    
        [C] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => matematika
                [ruangan] => ruangan3
                [guru] => Bapak Maman
            )
    
        [D] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => bahasa
                [ruangan] => ruangan4
                [guru] => Bapak Ringgo
            )
    
        [E] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => olahraga
                [ruangan] => ruangan5
                [guru] => Bapak Maman
            )
    
        [F] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => sejarah
                [ruangan] => ruangan6
                [guru] => Bapak Gugun
            )
    
)
kamis=>array(
     [A] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => biologi
                [ruangan] => ruangan1
                [guru] => Bapak Ringgo
            )
    
        [B] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => fisika
                [ruangan] => ruangan2
                [guru] => Bapak Gugun
            )
    
        [C] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => matematika
                [ruangan] => ruangan3
                [guru] => Bapak Maman
            )
    
        [D] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => bahasa
                [ruangan] => ruangan4
                [guru] => Ibu Anik
            )
    
        [E] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => olahraga
                [ruangan] => ruangan5
                [guru] => Ibu Lia
            )
    
        [F] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => sejarah
                [ruangan] => ruangan6
                [guru] => Ibu ucik
            )
    
)
kamis=>array(
     [A] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => biologi
                [ruangan] => ruangan1
                [guru] => Bapak Ringgo
            )
    
        [B] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => fisika
                [ruangan] => ruangan2
                [guru] => Bapak Gugun
            )
    
        [C] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => matematika
                [ruangan] => ruangan3
                [guru] => Bapak Maman
            )
    
        [D] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => bahasa
                [ruangan] => ruangan4
                [guru] => Ibu Anik
            )
    
        [E] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => olahraga
                [ruangan] => ruangan5
                [guru] => Ibu Lia
            )
    
        [F] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => sejarah
                [ruangan] => ruangan6
                [guru] => Ibu ucik
            )
    
)

jumat=>array(
     [A] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => biologi
                [ruangan] => ruangan1
                [guru] => Bapak Ringgo
            )
    
        [B] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => fisika
                [ruangan] => ruangan2
                [guru] => Bapak Gugun
            )
    
        [C] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => matematika
                [ruangan] => ruangan3
                [guru] => Bapak Maman
            )
    
        [D] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => bahasa
                [ruangan] => ruangan4
                [guru] => Ibu Anik
            )
    
        [E] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => olahraga
                [ruangan] => ruangan5
                [guru] => Ibu Lia
            )
    
        [F] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => sejarah
                [ruangan] => ruangan6
                [guru] => Ibu ucik
            )
)
sabtu=>array(
     [A] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => biologi
                [ruangan] => ruangan1
                [guru] => Bapak Ringgo
            )
    
        [B] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => fisika
                [ruangan] => ruangan2
                [guru] => Bapak Gugun
            )
    
        [C] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => matematika
                [ruangan] => ruangan3
                [guru] => Bapak Maman
            )
    
        [D] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => bahasa
                [ruangan] => ruangan4
                [guru] => Ibu Anik
            )
    
        [E] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => olahraga
                [ruangan] => ruangan5
                [guru] => Ibu Lia
            )
    
        [F] => Array
            (
                [pelajaran] => sejarah
                [ruangan] => ruangan6
                [guru] => Ibu ucik
            )
    
)
```

for my code

```
$sekolah = [
    "pelajaran" => ["biologi", "fisika", "matematika", "bahasa", "olahraga", "sejarah"],
    "kelas" => ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
    "ruangan" => ["ruangan1", "ruangan2", "ruangan3", "ruangan4", "ruangan5", "ruangan6"],
    "guru" => ["Pak Ringgo", "Pak Gugun", "Pak Maman", "Bu Anik", "Bu Lia", "Bu ucik"]
];


$hari = ["senin", "selasa", "rabu", "kamis", "jumat", "sabtu"];

$kelas = array();
$pelajaran = array();
$ruangan = array();
$guru = array();
$new_array = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($hari); $i++) {
    if (array_key_exists("kelas", $sekolah) && array_key_exists("pelajaran", $sekolah) && array_key_exists("ruangan", $sekolah) && array_key_exists("guru", $sekolah)) {
        $kelas = $sekolah['kelas'];
        $pelajaran = $sekolah['pelajaran'];
        $ruangan = $sekolah['ruangan'];
        $guru = $sekolah['guru'];
    }
}
$find = array('Pak', 'Bu');
$replace   = array('Bapak', 'Ibu');
$newguru = array();
$newguru =  str_replace($find, $replace, $guru);
$temp=array();
$penjadwalan = array();
foreach ($kelas as $datakelas => $valuesdata) {
    $new_array[] = [
        'pelajaran' => $pelajaran[$datakelas],
        'ruangan' => $ruangan[$datakelas],
        'guru' => $newguru[$datakelas]
    ];
}     
foreach ($hari as $datahari => $valueshari) {
    $datahari = [
       "kelas" => $new_array
    ];
}          
$temp= array_combine($kelas, $new_array);
print_r(array_combine($hari,$temp));
print_r($temp);
print_r($hari);
```

Comment: What did you try? Can you show some example code of your work?

Comment: wait i wil edit

Comment: i just done edit

Comment: text is always prefered to pictures of code or data

Comment: And are you sure that "RESULT I WANT" Is right, it changed a lot between when you had it as text and when you made it into a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with Bahasa to actually understand all the nouns in the code. I am guessing that you're just mapping the school information to the days of week here. So this might be what you needed:

```php
<?php

$sekolah = [
    "pelajaran" => ["biologi", "fisika", "matematika", "bahasa", "olahraga", "sejarah"],
    "kelas" => ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
    "ruangan" => ["ruangan1", "ruangan2", "ruangan3", "ruangan4", "ruangan5", "ruangan6"],
    "guru" => ["Pak Ringgo", "Pak Gugun", "Pak Maman", "Bu Anik", "Bu Lia", "Bu ucik"]
];


$hari = ["senin", "selasa", "rabu", "kamis", "jumat", "sabtu"];

$kelas = array();
$pelajaran = array();
$ruangan = array();
$guru = array();
$new_array = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($hari); $i++) {
    if (array_key_exists("kelas", $sekolah) && array_key_exists("pelajaran", $sekolah) && array_key_exists("ruangan", $sekolah) && array_key_exists("guru", $sekolah)) {
        $kelas = $sekolah['kelas'];
        $pelajaran = $sekolah['pelajaran'];
        $ruangan = $sekolah['ruangan'];
        $guru = $sekolah['guru'];
    }
}
$find = array('Pak', 'Bu');
$replace   = array('Bapak', 'Ibu');
$newguru = array();
$newguru =  str_replace($find, $replace, $guru);
$temp=array();
$penjadwalan = array();
foreach ($kelas as $datakelas => $valuesdata) {
    $new_array[] = [
        'pelajaran' => $pelajaran[$datakelas],
        'ruangan' => $ruangan[$datakelas],
        'guru' => $newguru[$datakelas]
    ];
}


foreach ($hari as $datahari => $valueshari) {
    $datahari = [
       "kelas" => $new_array
    ];
}
$temp = array_combine($kelas, $new_array);

// This is what I added
$result = [];
foreach ($hari as $day_of_week) {
    $result[$day_of_week] = $temp;
}

print_r($temp);
print_r($hari);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: thx tha'ts what i want actualy i forget in my question i want randomize data pelajaran in each day and female teacher only in last 3 days of week but its oke i will continue by myself 

thx koala yeung